# bash: how to pipe output string to a file to be used as parameter in the next step?

Tags: bash, unix

basically convert a xml file using xml2csv into a csv file but I want to directly pipe this as a parameter for my next python script. Basically I want to avoid creating any uncessary files and prefer a single command that will just pipe through all the data without problems.

```
./xml2csv raw.xml | python csv2json.py $outputfromlastrun > output.json
```

Comment: Do you have control of where `xml2csv` writes? what happens if you specify `-` as the target?

Comment: And what is the problem? what is `$outputfromlastrun`?

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution to save the output in a variable instead of a file:

```
outputfromlastrun=$(./xml2csv raw.xml | python csv2json.py "$outputfromlastrun")
```

Comment: close but this gives me `csv2json.py: error: argument input: can't open '': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`. it seems like it expects a filename. im trying to stream to some temp filename so it can read the csv into json output....

Comment: Does `csv2json.py` allow you to provide both a filename and also read from standard input? I'm not sure I understand how you want to use the current file and the output from the previous run.

Comment: If the output from the last run is already JSON, you can't feed that as input to `csv2json.py`. It seems like you'd first need to convert that back to CSV, combine it with the new output of `xml2csv`, and then feed that all to the next run of `csv2json`.

Comment: it does not read from standard input. it only accepts a filename. here's the source code https://gist.github.com/hlawrenz/1ef3490cb9aa021297a0#file-csv2json-py

Comment: It does accept standard input, because `args.input` has `default=[sys.stdin]`

Comment: You still haven't explained how you want to merge `raw.xml` with `$outputfromlastrun`.